# How is the index stored in cloud data

Tags: cloud

I have been reading on the internet and i found this.

For searching the cloud for encrypted data/files it uses encrypted index. So to know about these index and how index is made, I could'nt find it.

Can anyone help in telling me where I can find about the index or can anyone tell me how the index is made?

Comment: Cloud isn't a single thing. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Again, what is this "public cloud"? Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: http://www.eci.com/cloudforum/private-cloud-explained.html